# What do these Mugen round-win icons mean?

Tags: mugen

[image]

[image]

I know that `V` is just for "Victory", appears if you finish your opponent with a basic attack. `S` is for a "Super" move, and `H` is for "Hyper". But what do these icons (encircled in red) indicate?

(Mugen version: 1.0 (18 Jan 2011))

Comment: I think the first one is winning via cheese.  I'm not sure what the 2nd is.

Comment: @Luck Wining by "cheese" or "cheating"? If "cheating" by pressing F1 key,  skull icon appears. These icons in the images are something different.

Comment: I meant "cheese".  I believe it's triggered by winning via chip damage.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be the same icons as in Street Fighter Alpha series:

- **Cheese** - when you win while the adversary was blocking (see [cheap / cheese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_fighting_games#Cheap_.2F_Cheese)).
- **Lasso** - when you win by grabbing/throwing the adversary.